# Securing a route to use a refresh token

Tags: angular

The route configuration is making use of an `isAuthenticated` service method :

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
  const expectedRole = route.data.expectedRole ? route.data.expectedRole : null;
  const tokenPayload = this.authService.getDecodedAccessToken();
  const role = tokenPayload.role ? tokenPayload.role : null;
  if (!this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
    return false;
  } else if (role != null && role !== expectedRole) {
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

This method is checking the access token validity in the browser local storage without yet trying to use a refresh token :

```
public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
  const token = this.getAccessTokenFromLocalStorage();
  return (token && !this.jwtHelperService.isTokenExpired(token));
}
```

I wonder how to go about using the refresh token.

I was hoping to have my interceptor do the job :

```
return this.refreshToken()
.pipe(
  switchMap(() => {
    request = this.addAccessToken(request);
    return next.handle(request);
  })
)
.pipe(
  catchError(
    (refreshError) => {
      this.authService.logout();
      return empty();
      // return throwError(refreshError); TODO
    })
);
```

The refresh token is then sent in the request :

```
private refreshToken() {
  if (this.refreshTokenInProgress) {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      this.tokenRefreshed$.subscribe(() => {
        observer.next();
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  } else {
    this.refreshTokenInProgress = true;
    console.log('Sending a refresh token request...');
    return this.authService.refreshAccessToken()
      .pipe(
        tap(() => {
          console.log('The refresh token has been received');
          this.refreshTokenInProgress = false;
          this.tokenRefreshedSource.next();
        })
      );
  }
}
```

The renewed access token is then added to the next request :

```
private addAccessToken(request): HttpRequest<any> {
  if (!this.tokenService.getAccessTokenFromLocalStorage()) {
    return request;
  }

  // The original request is immutable and cannot be changed
  return this.authService.addAccessTokenToClonedRequest(request);
}
```

But for now, my `isAuthenticated` method completely ignores this.

Should I modify the `isAuthenticated` method to have it call the `refreshToken` method ? Or is there a way to plug the interceptor into the route configuration ?

UPDATE:

I modified the `isAuthenticated` method :

```
public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
  let isAuthenticated = false;
  if (this.tokenService.accessTokenIsNotExpired()) {
    isAuthenticated = true;
  } else {
    if (this.tokenService.refreshTokenIsNotExpired()) {
      this.refreshAccessToken()
      .pipe(
        map(() => {
          console.log('The access token has been refreshed');
          // TODO How to resend this unauthorized request ?
        })
      );
    }
  }
  return isAuthenticated;
}
```

But then the refresh token response is asynchronous, whereas the `canActivate` property is synchronous. So I suppose I lose the unauthorized request in the updated method above. Is there any way to resend this unauthorized request ?

Also, what to do with my beautiful interceptor ? Shall it remain unused for the access token refreshing part ? UPDATE : I can answer that one now : the interceptor access token refreshing is getting used when the access token is still valid when the client looks it up in the `isAuthenticated` method, but is then not valid any longer when the request arrives to the REST token refresh endpoint and the server checks the token. I'd say so.

UPDATE : 
I also tried this method but it didn't help :

```
public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
  let isAuthenticated = true;
  if (this.tokenService.accessTokenExpired()) {
    isAuthenticated = false;
    if (this.tokenService.refreshTokenExpired()) {
      isAuthenticated = false;
    } else {
      this.refreshAccessToken()
        .pipe(
          map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
            console.log('The access token has been refreshed');
          }),
          catchError((error, caught) => {
            console.log('The access token has not been refresh');
            console.log(error);
            return empty();
          })
        );
    }
  }
  return isAuthenticated;
}
```

UPDATE : It nows works fine, the refresh token does renew the access token. And the routing is behaving as expected.

I changed the `canActivate` method as it can use an `Observable` too in fact :

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
  const expectedRole = route.data.expectedRole ? route.data.expectedRole : null;
  const tokenPayload = this.tokenService.getDecodedAccessToken();
  return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
  .pipe(
    map(isAuth => {
      console.log('A response was returned');
      console.log(isAuth);
      if (!isAuth) {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }),
    catchError((error, caught) => {
      console.log('An error was returned');
      console.log(error);
      return of(false);
    })
  );
}
```

With the `isAuthenticated` method now looking like :

```
public isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
  if (this.tokenService.accessTokenExpired()) {
    console.log('The access token expired.');
    if (this.tokenService.refreshTokenExpired()) {
      console.log('The refresh token expired.');
      return of(false);
    } else {
      return this.refreshAccessToken()
      .pipe(
        map(response => {
          if (response) {
            console.log('The access token has been refreshed');
            return true;
          }
        }),
        catchError((error, caught) => {
          console.log('The access token could not be refreshed');
          console.log(error);
          return of(false);
        })
      );
    }
  }
  return of(true);
}

public refreshAccessToken(): Observable<any> {
  console.log('Sending the refresh token to obtain a new access token');
  let httpHeaders: HttpHeaders = this.httpService.buildHeader(null);
  httpHeaders = this.addRefreshTokenHeader(httpHeaders);
  httpHeaders = this.addClientIdHeader(httpHeaders);

  return this.httpService.postWithHeadersInResponse(URI_REFRESH_TOKEN, {}, httpHeaders)
    .pipe(
      map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        // Only the access token is refreshed
        // Refresing the refresh token would be like giving a never expiring refresh token
        this.storeAccessTokenInLocalStorage(response);
        console.log('Stored the refreshed access token in the local storage');
        return true;
      })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid refreshing the token on every HTTP request I used [rxjs Scheduler](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/scheduler.md) to refresh the session before the expiration.

Don't refresh on every request. The user might be using the webpage(maybe writing a message) but not sending requests, so the user is active and yet the session would expire anyway.

Don't trust the expiration time field in the JWT to calculate when to refresh the token because the server might have a different time than the client. Adjust the time differences in your calculations if needed.

Also, when using refresh token, remember to set a time limit for the refresh. Otherwise, a user might have an infinite session by just refreshing over and over.

Those are the issues I faced. The client had requested session expiration after 8 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: I plan to have an access token expire after an hour and a refresh token expire after a week.

Comment: The trouble I have is that I get an unauthorized as the token refresh asynchronous process leaves the `isAuthenticated` to false, redirecting the user to the login page.

Comment: So you are not using the `canActivate` feature ? How do you secure your routes then ? Or if you do use it, how do you have it play with the refresh token renewing the access token server side ?

Comment: I don't think that you should refresh token automatically. If user is watching video, or writing book, (even if it could be 1 week), for different cases like these, you should refresh token case by case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right.

In my case, the refresh token is JWT and as in your case, I was saving both Refresh and Access tokens in local storage. Never save them in local storage. authentication tokens could be saved only in cookies with httpOnly flag.

In route guard I watch if the refresh token is expired or not, and I'm using angular2-jwt package from Auth0 for that.

Also, and if your opened page will not call any http requests, you should do one http request for check if access token is expired and refresh it. You can do it in guard too, it depends on application.

Comment: All in all, you understood my question :-)